# MongoDB does not remove documents from a collection with a configured TTL Index

Tags: mongodb

I try to get started with TTL indices in mongo, and wanted to get a simple demo setup running, but I just cannot get it to work and I am not sure what I do wrong.

Mongod version:

```
$ mongod --version
db version v4.4.5
Build Info: {
    "version": "4.4.5",
    "gitVersion": "ff5cb77101b052fa02da43b8538093486cf9b3f7",
    "openSSLVersion": "OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "tcmalloc",
    "environment": {
        "distmod": "debian10",
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}
```

I start with a completely fresh, default configured mongod instance:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/db && mongod --dbpath /tmp/db
```

Then I run the following commands

```
use test

db.ttldemo.insertOne({
    created_at: Date(Date.now() + 60_000)
})


db.ttldemo.createIndex({created_at: 1}, {expireAfterSeconds: 1})

db.ttldemo.find()
```

I would expect the document to vanish after some time, but even after running `find()` after waiting for a few minutes, the document is still present.

Is there anything I am missing here?

`db.adminCommand({getParameter:1, ttlMonitorSleepSecs: 1})` yields `60` to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried in mongo 4.2.17, your insertion of documents yields a document like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61f17ea34844b5f0505d80ea"),
    "created_at" : "Wed Jan 26 2022 19:02:27 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)"
}
```

when the

```
db.getCollection('ttldemo').insertOne({created_at: new Date()})
```

yields a document like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61f17f404844b5f0505d80ec"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2022-01-26T17:05:04.023Z")
}
```

Emphasis here on the created_at field, where this on the first case is a string, in the second case is an ISODate.
as from the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/) , this index works on dates only:

> To create a TTL index, use the createIndex() method on a field whose value is either a date or an array that contains date values, and specify the expireAfterSeconds option with the desired TTL value in seconds.

The solution here is to construct the date as follows:

```
db.getCollection('ttldemo').insertOne({created_at: new Date(new Date().getTime()+60000)})
```

this will create a new ISODate based on the current date + 60 seconds.

Comment: God, now I feel stupid. Didn't realize that `Date(...)` creates a String instead of a Date object, and thought the String I see via `find` is just how my mongo client shows dates to me. Thanks!

Comment: yeah :) I always check datatypes first. Always check the mongo documents in JSON format, some clients can be misleading since you don't know the exact type of some fields.